# Issue in React useReducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to do the 2048 game in ReactJs and I am using functional component to keep it simple.
how my below code works is when i press the up key every data in the state changes and the state is a 2d array.I am new to functional component and I See many things are going out of control.

```
function reducer(state, action){
    console.warn('INSIDE REDUCER')
    switch (action.type){
      case 'UP':
        console.warn("UP");
        return action.payload
    }
}

function App() {
  
  
  let [ boxes, dispatch ] = useReducer(reducer, [[2,4,2,4],[2,'',2,''],[8,16,2,2],['',2,2,'']])
  
  let moveup = () =>{
    //code that will change the state(boxes)
    let tempboxes = boxes
    tempboxes.map((each)=>{
      //maps through each subarrays and change the values
    })
    console.log(boxes) //i was surprised as well as shocked here because i never changed the state(boxes) anywhere
    dispatch({type: 'UP',payload:tempboxes}) //Note i called dispatch after console.log but am seeing the state update here.  
  }
  
  // event handling function to get the arrow keys input
  document.onkeydown = function(event) {
  switch (event.keyCode) {
   //other keys
   case 38:
        console.log('Up key pressed');
        moveup();
      break;
}}
return(
 //jsx part)
}


export default App;
```

The logic is working fine as expected but in the below image you can clearly see that my boxes state is updating even though i didnt changed a bit of it(as its before dispatch) and after calling dispatch its not even calling reducer function(didnt get the INSIDE REDUCER warning).

[image]

Is this the way we use functions inside functional component? where its going wrong?

Comment: You are not doing anything with the return value of map and probably mutate items there (you did not provide the code). You should use map [the way it was intended to be](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#When_not_to_use_map) and use the returned new array. In the map callback you also should not mutate items. [Here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#updating-an-item-in-an-array) is some information on how to update item(s) in an array.

Comment: @HMR I tried using forEach instead of map as well but getting the same as the above

Comment: Using forEach is even dumber because this will explicitly mutate state. How to update without mutating is explained [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#updating-an-item-in-an-array)

Comment: Thanks @HMR . even though we mutate any array it will affect the state. we only need to return the value and after update that in a state. found your comment helpful